# Javascript data input Json

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have data on a website which looks like this

```
[{"id":213877,"pic":"https://graph.facebook.com/ariel.barack/picture?type=square","url":"https://angel.co/ariel-barack","name":"Ariel Barack","type":"User"},{"id":109396,"pic":"https://d1qb2nb5cznatu.cloudfront.net/users/109396-medium_jpg?1405528556","url":"https://angel.co/mattbarackman","name":"Matt Barackman","type":"User"},{"id":881384,"pic":null,"url":"https://angel.co/austin-barack","name":"Austin Barack","type":"User"},{"id":245752,"pic":null,"url":"https://angel.co/drgoddess","name":"Dr. Goddess","type":"User"}]
```

I have a html file with javascript code as follows:

```
function httpGet(url) {
var xmlHttp = null;

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
var data = xmlHttp.responseText;
data = (JSON.parse(data));
```

I need to access the "name" attribute from the URL database and form a string concat of all the name attributes. Could you please help me out what to be done next?

Comment: Can you plz paste how you want the output

Comment: The concatenation of the name attributes:Ariel Barack Austin Barack Dr. Goddess

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = data.map(function(user) {
  return user.name;
}).join('');
```

Comment: And how do i print this ? document.write(data)?

Comment: @user3371307 var result

Answer (score 0):

Below is my test data

```
var data = '{"name": "mkyong","age": 30,"address": {"streetAddress": "88 8nd Street","city": "New York"},"phoneNumber": [{"type": "home","number": "111 111-1111"},{"type": "fax","number": "222 222-2222"}]}';

        var json = JSON.parse(data);

        alert(json["name"]); //mkyong
        alert(json.name);
```

For Example if you want to acces the name you can access as like above.

To concatenate the vales do like below

```
    var Output  = json.map(function(result) {
      return result.name;
    }).join('');

   alert(Output);
```

Have a look on it  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun(){
        var str='[{"id":213877,"pic":"https://graph.facebook.com/ariel.barack/picture?type=square","url":"https://angel.co/ariel-barack","name":"Ariel Barack","type":"User"},{"id":109396,"pic":"https://d1qb2nb5cznatu.cloudfront.net/users/109396-medium_jpg?1405528556","url":"https://angel.co/mattbarackman","name":"Matt Barackman","type":"User"},{"id":881384,"pic":null,"url":"https://angel.co/austin-barack","name":"Austin Barack","type":"User"},{"id":245752,"pic":null,"url":"https://angel.co/drgoddess","name":"Dr. Goddess","type":"User"}]';
        var obj=eval(str);
        var names='';
        for(var item in obj){
            names+=obj[item].name;
        }
        alert(names);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="click me"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I am specifically using this:var url= "https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=User";


function httpGet(url) {
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    var data = xmlHttp.responseText;
    data = (JSON.parse(data));

Comment: I need to output the concatenated string onto the webpage.

Comment: Since you already have the 'name' variable, you can output the string to the webpage via sorts of way. For example,you can put an input tag on the page and set the value to the 'name' variable.

Comment: You can copy the codes above into a file such as 'demo.html' and try run it in internet explore.

Comment: Ye i know, but i am not getting the output

Comment: Hey, I used multiple document.write statements and find out that the program is having errors beginning from this line "xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false ); " .Any idea why?

Comment: I got what you mean.It is the Ajax problem.If you really use the code that you provided,it should not work.Here is the Ajax code to get response from a certain url:

Answer (score 0):

I got what you mean.It is the Ajax problem.If you really use the code that you provided,it should not work.Here is the Ajax code to get response from a certain url:

```
var ajaxRequest;
//create ajax object
function createAjaxRequest() {
            var xmlhttp = null;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for all new browsers
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {// code for IE5 and IE6
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            return xmlhttp;
        }
//send request and identify callbak handler
function send(url) {

            ajaxRequest = createAjaxRequest();
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = callback;
            ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);
            ajaxRequest.send(null);
        }
// the callback handler
function callback() {
            if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {// 4 = "loaded"
                if (ajaxRequest.status == 200) {// 200 = OK
                    var data = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Problem retrieving  data");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think the data is being read from url but the string concatenation function is still not working

Comment: Hey, I am sorry. I am constantly getting "Problem retrieving data" alert

Comment: How come?Did you try my code? I mean did you copy my code to a local file 'demao.html' and try to run it?

Comment: Ye I copied into a .html file and it pops up with this error

Comment: what error?Tell me the explore name,ie ? firefox? chrome?

Comment: chrome. A dialog alert is displayed with "Problem retrieving data"

Comment: Of course you got this alert.This is all because you did not have the corrent url.To achive this url, you should first have a server and then post this request to that server.

Comment: the url that i use works perfectly fine. I am basically trying to use the data obtained from API and try to concatenate them. This is the url that I am currently using:https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=User